# Make a transistor act as a potentiometer

Tags: bjt, potentiometer, linear

So, how would one get a transistor (probably BJT) to act somewhat like a potentiometer? What I trying to do is have xl6009 buck boost regulator be electronically controlled to charge a li-ion battery pack i.e. using a micro controller to implement CV and CC. Ideally I would insert some kind of transistor into the feedback loop (instead of the normal 10k potentiometer) and thus vary the output voltage. The problem is most BJT's I've seen don't seem to have a large active (linear) region AND the resistances in those regions are too small to allow a broad range of output.
[image]

Comment: That's why we use JFETs instead.

Comment: You don't think of transistors as variable resistors, you have to think of them as current control devices. For a more detailed answer I would have to see the circuit of your regulator.

Comment: Using those modules with a microcontroller has been one of my ideas for years ;) I thought of using an op-amp to "calculate" `Vfb = k * Vout - j * Vdac + 1.25V`. This way I think I can regulate Vout to be j/k * Vdac, since the regulator sets the voltage to have 1.25V. Then regulating k and j I can also set the responsiveness of the ring, thus avoiding instabilities. But I never investigated too much in this because of time...

Comment: And of course Vdac is the output of a DAC, so controlled by a microcontroller

Comment: Don't try to roll your own Li-ion charger. Just buy an IC. Whatever you don't catch on fire will thank you.

Comment: You're describing your intended solution, but you should be describing your problem. This question should be "how do I control the output voltage of this regulator?"

Comment: Yeah but i don't intend to jump in and jerry rig something right away I just want to be theoretical and maybe eventually implement something. I like how buck boost could work off a computer power supply and be very efficient as opposed to an IC

Comment: how do I control the output voltage of this regulator?

Comment: those batteries scare me. If I do do something with the battery packs ill use the protection circuits that come with them.

Answer (score 1):

The feedback input pin on the device will normally be sitting at 1.25 volts when the output is at the correct level. R1 and R2 and the output level of 18.5 volts produce exactly 1.25 volts on this pin.

However, if you inject a DC current into the junction of R1 and R2 you are telling the chip that it is creating too much output voltage and therefore the chip will alter its duty cycle accordingly and produce a lower output voltage.

This is the way to control the device - use a DAC and current source. You can compromise this to a DAC, an op-amp gain stage and a biggish valued resistor. This can be further compromised using a DAC and a medium value resistor. To avoid changing the base value you need to ensure that your DAC can produce 1.25 volts. If you want the output level to fall inject current into the node.

If you want the output to rise above the "nominal" take current from the node but be careful because you don't need to take much before the output voltage possibly doubles.

So, don't try and pursue getting a transistor to act as a pot. About the only similarity is that it has three terminals. Injecting/extracting current is the clean way of doing it.

Comment: Extra tip: If you want to do something via the feedback input you could use a diode to only be able to pull the feedback pin up (in voltage) that way you can only make the output voltage go lower. This can prevent the situation that the feedback pin is pulled down, the IC thinking the output voltage is too low and increasing it to a value above what you might want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a digital pot to adjust the output voltage of this regulator. The only tricky bit is that typically a digital pot can't withstand a higher voltage than the logic supply voltage on any of its pins. So, assuming a 5V logic supply, we can do something like this (assume a digital pot such as the [MCP4018](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22147a.pdf), but there are many other types).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYziQj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We need the voltage on the 'high' side of RV1 to be <= 5V under all conditions, so that constrains R1 to be no less than 3.33K. That results in a 4:1 range in output voltage (5V/1.25V) for the XL6009 with its 1.25V reference.

R1(min) = \$\text R_{V1}\over(\frac {V_{supply}}{V_{REF} }-1)\$

You can easily calculate the value of Rx from the maximum desired output voltage to be:

Rx = 
  \$\frac {V_{MAX} R_1}{V_{REF}}-(R_{V1}+R_1)\$

So, suppose you wanted 12V maximum output voltage and you used 3.33K for R1, then Rx would be 18.6K, and the output voltage range would be 3V to 12V (4:1).

Note: I've deliberately ignored tolerances and such like- but you shouldn't. Often the digital pot (like mechanical pots) has a poor tolerance for the total resistance. That *must* be taken into account when doing the calculations. In practice that means you won't get quite 4:1 range in the situation described.

Comment: Also, to the reader, be aware of digipot temperature coefficients in rheostat and Pot divider mode - these need to be factored in too. However, you can get decent ones like the AD5207 that doesn't have anything more than ~20ppm/degC down to 15:1 ratios.

Comment: As @Andyaka says, and/or you can reduce the effect of the 'element' tempco and tolerance by paralleling it with a fixed precision resistor, at the cost of increasing errors due to the regulator feedback input bias current or current draw. For example, you could use a 10K pot and parallel it with a 1K 1% resistor and reduce the other two resistors by multiplying by 1/11.0, which could allow a sow's ear to perform as a silk purse.

Answer (score 0):

The way to use a transistor to control the voltage output of your regulator would be to put an NPN BJT in series with the resistor R1, with emitter to ground. The transistor allows you to control the current through this resistor, from 0 to about (1.25-0.3)/R1, by controlling its base current - Ic is approximately Ib * hfe - effectively making it look as though R1 is variable.

You can then change the fixed values of R1 and R2 to give you the range of voltages you like.

You now have another question - how do you control the current into the base of the BJT to give you the output voltage you require?

The answer from @AndyAka is really the solution you are looking for.